# Is it okay to use mLab like a database for big web applications?

Tags: database, mongodb, mlab

How do you think, is it a good way to use mLab or better to install MongoDB on a server?
Is it safe to use mLab for big web apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mLab is now part of MongoDB so I recommend you look at [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). Epic Games runs Fortnite on MongoDB Atlas so it should be good enough for your big web app.